# TypeScript | Interfaces y Types

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, vscode

Antes que nada quisiera agradecer un poco de consideración ya que no conozco en absoluto sobre TypeScript.

Asumiendo que tengo un objeto en cuyas propiedades son dinámicas, es decir, podría ser que tenga una llave en un momento y al otro ya no la tenga, el detalle es que todas sus llaves tendrán la misma estructura de retorno, es decir, todas retornan un Número, quisiera saber como hacer una Interface que sin importar la llave que yo elija, ella siempre reconozca que su valor retornado será un número.

```
const scopes = {
  key: 23,
  key2: 211,
}
const scopes = ([{key:"key",value:23},{key:"key2",value:211}])
   .reduce((o, prop)=>({
     ...o,
     [prop.key]:prop.value
    }),{});
```

Ambos scopes tienen la misma estructura, solo que en el primero las llaves están pre-definidas, todo está en orden allí, pero en el segundo no conozco las llaves ni el arreglo, solo sé que su valor será un número, como hago para crear una interface así?

Comment: ¿Podrías ampliar tu pregunta agregando un ejemplo? La pregunta que haces queda muy al aire y no aporta información sufuciente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una interfaz de esta manera:

```
export interface Dato {
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

Esto le permitirá saber al compilador que puede contener cualquier clave, pero que debe de ser de tipo numérica.

Esto es correcto:

```
  this.dato["cualquiera"]=2
  this.dato["key2"]=2
```

Y esto tirara error:

```
 this.dato["cualquiera"]="2"
```